# MongoDB result as aggregated array of fields, not array of objects

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have collection of documents (~1 billion of items) and I want to get it as array of field. And in the same time I do not want to postprocess result of Mongo query.

Example:

```
// Collection looks alike

[
  {"_id": ObjectId("...", "id": "12313123", ....)},
  {"_id": ObjectId("...", "id": "35675468456", ....)}
  {"_id": ObjectId("...", "id": "23233463", ....)}
  ....
]

// Desired result
["12313123", "35675468456", "23233463"]
```

I.e I want to get only field `id` and make result flatten. But statement
`db.collection.find({}, {"_id": 0, "id": 1})` returns list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Would single-purpose aggregation  [db.collection.distinct("id")](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) work for you?

Comment: Yeah! That is what I want.